# Include non .NET project in Clickonce manifest

Tags: clickonce

Our .NET application is hosting non .NET application (using Process.Start()).  Can I include it in Clickonce options, so that if files of this non .NET app are changed, it would appear in the list of manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ClickOnce can deploy non-.Net files.  The one requirement is that the main, starting exe must be a .Net exectuable.